# Why does changing CRT to HDTV lose antenna channels?

Tags: antenna, tv, crt, hd

We have an internal antenna that is connected to a tiny CRT TV through a digital converter box.  I recently replaced this CRT TV with an HDTV, and I removed the digital converter box since the HDTV does not need it.   For some unforeseen reason, a few channels cannot be received on this TV at all.  So, I replaced the digital converter box, connected it to the HDTV and tried it, and a few of the channels came back, but not all of them.  I then put the CRT TV back, and the rest of the channels returned.

Why would replacing a CRT with an HDTV remove the channels if the antenna setup remains unchanged, even with the digital converter box still connected?  Is there any way to receive these lost channels on the HDTV?  It's already connected to an amplifier.

As a secondary question, why would the digital converter box change the number of channels the HDTV receives?

I'm sorry I don't have any specifications of the equipment.  If that becomes absolutely necessary, I can provide it, but I am more interested in the general theory of this change.

Comment: Did you scan for channels on the new TV? They need to identify what channels have anything other than noise on them first.

Comment: @Hearth Yes, I did this, and it in fact did not find many of the channels that showed up on the CRT.  I think of the TVs like computer monitors.  As long as the tech handshake works, the output signal from the antenna to the TV should be identical no matter what the display is, right? Or is there something tricky going on in the HDTV that is ignoring some signals or hiding them for some reason when I do its channel search?

Comment: It depends on what exactly the digital converter box is doing. I imagine many TVs nowadays aren't designed to pick up analog channels, and what the digital converter box *does* is take digital channels and convert them to analog so that old analog TVs can get them... There may also be some weird DRM stuff going on, because that's in TV now too I'm pretty sure.

Comment: this question is perilously close to a question about using consumer devices. (off topic)